# Update two tables Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to update 2 tables `tbl_loanledger` and `tbl_journal` at the same time. Both tables have the same columns such as `modified_by, date_modified and deleted`.

When I try to run this I enter code here I'm getting an error :

> Error Number: 1052
>
> Column 'modified_by' in field list is ambiguous
>
> UPDATE `loan_ledger` as a, journal as b SET `modified_by` = '1',
>   `date_modified` = '2016-06-08', `deleted` = 1 WHERE `a`.`id` = '823'
>   AND `b`.`id` = '823'
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 331

Is this the right way on how to update 2 tables in codeigniter?

**Model**

```
public function delete($id){

  $data = array(
        'modified_by' => $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id,
        'date_modified' => date("Y-m-d"),
        'deleted' => 1
      );

    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('a.id', $id);
    $this->db->where('b.id', $id);
    $this->db->update('loan_ledger as a, journal as b');

}
```

But if I am just updating single table, it is working, here is a the code:

```
public function delete($id){

  $data = array(
        'modified_by' => $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id,
        'date_modified' => date("Y-m-d"),
        'deleted' => 1
      );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update(tbl_loanledger, $data);

}
```

Comment: Use table name before column !!

Comment: sorry @Saty, what do you mean? I'm new to codeigniter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Use of join just write two seperate update query as

```
 // first 
    $this->db->set('a.modified_by', $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id);
    $this->db->set('a.date_modified', date("Y-m-d"));
    $this->db->set('a.deleted', 1);
    $this->db->where('a.id',  $id);
    $this->db->update('loan_ledger as a');
    // second
    $this->db->set('b.modified_by', $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id);
    $this->db->set('b.date_modified', date("Y-m-d"));
    $this->db->set('b.deleted', 1);
    $this->db->where('b.id',  $id);
    $this->db->update('journal as b');
```

Comment: It only update the first query, but not the second query

Comment: `$sql = $this->db->last_query();` use to print second query and check what it return

Comment: UPDATE `journal` as b SET `b`.`modified_by` = '1', `b`.`date_modified` = '2016-06-08', `b`.`deleted` = 1 WHERE `b`.`id` = '779', i tried running it in phpmyadmin and the result  0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0006 sec)

Comment: hAve you check database for second query??

Comment: yes i have checked it, by the way, thanks a lot for pointing out @saty, i think i know whats going on, i have to add another column for the table journal

Comment: glad to know you got your mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function delete($id){

$data = array(
    'a.modified_by' => $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id,
    'a.date_modified' => date("Y-m-d"),
    'b.modified_by' => $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id,
    'b.date_modified' => date("Y-m-d"),  
    'deleted' => 1
  );

$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where('a.id', $id);
$this->db->where('b.id', $id);
$this->db->update('loan_ledger as a, journal as b');

}
```

Comment: Not working @kc1994 it doesn't update anymore, i tried updating as well 'a.deleted' => 1 and 'b.deleted' => 1, but no luck

Comment: try to print query ,and  see where is issue

Comment: sorry, can you help me how?

Comment: $this->db->last_query();

Comment: it doesn't print any, i just add it before the } in the Model

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: UPDATE `loan_ledger` as a, journal as b SET `a`.`modified_by` = '1', `a`.`date_modified` = '2016-06-08', `a`.`deleted` = 1, `b`.`modified_by` = '1', `b`.`date_modified` = '2016-06-08', `b`.`deleted` = 1 WHERE `a`.`id` = '823' AND `b`.`id` = '823'

Comment: execute this query in phpmydmin

Comment: 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0008 sec)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$this->db->set('a.modified_by', $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id);
$this->db->set('a.date_modified', date("Y-m-d"));
$this->db->set('a.deleted', 1);

$this->db->set('b.modified_by', $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id);
$this->db->set('b.date_modified', date("Y-m-d"));
$this->db->set('b.deleted', 1);

$this->db->where('a.id',  $id);
$this->db->where('a.id = b.id');
$this->db->update('loan_ledger as a, journal as b');
?>
```